# change DOM object dataset at once

Tags: javascript

The case is simple:

I have a JavaScript object

```
myData = {foo : 'foo', bar : 'bar'};
```

And I have a DOM object

```
myDOMObj = document.getElementById('myDOMObj');
```

Of course, now

```
myDOMObj.dataset === {/* whatever */};
```

And, simple as this, what I would like to do is to change completely all such dataset to the one from `myData`, that is, I would like to achieve something like:

```
myDOMObj.dataset = myData;

//so now we would have...
myDOMObj.dataset = {foo : 'foo', bar : 'bar'};
```

However, this doesn't seem to work, and I wonder if there is a clean way, other than iterating over the dataset elements:

```
for (propertyName in data) {
    myDOMObj.dataset[propertyName] = data[propertyName];
}
```

Which, of course, works, but it is not as clean...